# Liftweb - LiftScreen and ajax

Tags: scala, uitextfield, lift

I am trying to use Liftscreen to implement a form in ajax but I want to use Ajax, that is to say that I want the `finish` function to be called whenever a field is updated. Usually I use functions like `SHtml.ajaxText` to achieve this goal but I would prefer to use `LiftScreen` as it already has a lot of routines included.

Here is a basic example of code I am using

```
class ScreenTest extends LiftScreen {

  // here are the fields and default values
  val name = field("Name", "")

  // the age has validation rules
  val age = field("Age", 0, minVal(13, "Too Young"))

  def finish() {
    println("-------> Finish function has be called")
    S.notice("Name: "+name)
    S.notice("Age: "+age)
  }
}
```

So I would like the finish function to be called whenever the field `name` or `age` is called. I would prefer a general setting instead of manually calling `finish` in each field.

**Update**  I am working on a search engine depending on some criteria, so I want my results to be updated whenever a criteria is modified.

I already read the documentation page about LiftScreen on [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/LiftScreen) and I also found a discussion about [ajax on LiftScreen](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/xoio6voRZFM) on the official mailing list (which I will contact if I can't find any answer in here)

Comment: What do you mean by "called" ? Is that on focus ?

Comment: @Lukasz I mean that I want the function finish() to print name and age whenever either name or age is modified. I am working on a search engine depending on some criteria, so I want my results to be updated whenever a criteria is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a small javascript to the template you are using for your screen (wizard-all ?). For instance:

```
jQuery('input').change(function() {
    jQuery('#idOfForm').submit();
});
```

Not sure if it is possible to add such a script from the LiftScreen snippet.

**EDIT**
Another way would be to use a custom field as described in the wiki [here](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Add_custom_field_types_to_LiftScreen). I think you could do something along the lines of:

```
object AjaxifiedScreen extends LiftScreen { 
  val name = new Field { 
    type ValueType = String 
    override def name = "name" 
    override implicit def manifest = buildIt[String] 
    override def default = "" 
    override def toForm: Box[NodeSeq] = SHtml.ajaxText(is, doStuff(_)) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes but I was looking for a more global solution already implemented in LiftScreen, however if it does not exist I will have to use this method.

Comment: Edited answer. I believe that with an ajaxText you can get it to work with an onblur event.

Comment: This is effectively closer to my vision, I hopped that it existed a "default" behaviour, but as it seems that it is not the case, I will use this, thanks a lot for your help.